# Initialize pointer to pointer on the stack

Tags: c, pointers, memory, stack

I'm a C newbie, and I'm trying to do the pointer/memory thing right...

In my case, I'm using strtol and I need to pass a **char to hold one of several return values, but allocating heap space is way overkill.  The cleanest correct (I hope) way I can find, of getting space on the stack for this, is:

```
char *_ = NULL;
char **endptr = &_;
ret = strtol("not a number", endptr, 0);
```

I'm curious, is there a more succinct or idiomatic way to get this effect?  I feel dirty naming things I will never use...

EDIT:
to clarify, I DO intend to use endptr, just not _

Comment: `_` is something many would consider a questionable choice for a variable name.

Comment: Fair enough.  In many functional languages it is the conventional way to pattern match on a value you will not use.  Is there a C convention for this sort of thing?

Comment: `char *endptr;` `strtol(str, &endptr, 0);`. In other words, declare `endptr` as a pointer, and then pass the address of that pointer to `strtol`.

Comment: The edit makes no sense. `endptr` is not good for anything other than pointing to `_`. But you can access `_` directly. And if you don't use `_`, you can pass `NULL` as others pointed out.

Comment: Okay.  Nit-picky I guess.  I intend to use endptr and _, but I don't need variables for both of them simultaneously.

Comment: @Shane: Names starting with `_` are reserved for the implementation. And it is a bad choice in an imerative programming language. Don't use it. As  a general rule, use the features a languages supports and follow its paradigm(s). Otherwise you will soon become a Don Quixote.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, I agree... I appreciate the pointer, and that it's a language reserved name is a fact I'm quite happy to know, but I think this has much less to do with paradigms than with languages.  In plenty of imperative languages the use of underscore to mean unused is perfectly idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtol` accepts `NULL` as the second argument. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

So you can write your code like this:

```
ret = strtol("not a number", NULL, 0);
```

If it didn't accept NULL, you can avoid one line of code like this:

```
char *unused;
ret = strtol("not a number", &unused, 0);
```

Comment: So, despite lack of initialization, space for *unused will always be on the stack, and &unused will be a valid stack address?

Comment: @Shane No, `unused` is on the stack and `*unused` is undefined because `unusued`'s pointee isn't set. Compare to: `int x; printf("%p", &x);` which prints the address of `x` even though `x` isn't initialized.

Comment: note that you do need to use `endptr` if you want to find out whether a result of `0` is due to the input being not-a-number, or the input actually being `0`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need endptr, you are allowed to pass a null pointer to strtol. Otherwise I wouldn't worry about naming a variable you won't use. Although I don't think I'd name it `_` as you have.